# Using 'real values' in imshow in python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, imshow

I would like to plot a heatmap using the `imshow()` module, however I am struggling to get it to work the way I would like to. My data is stored in `pandas` dataframe which consists of 100-1000 columns, each column with 201 rows. The first row in each column is a value I would like to use on my x-axis, whereas remaining 200 rows are the data points to be used in `imshow` plot.

Here is the structure of my dataframe (the values do eventually increase from 0.0000):
[image]

The first column is just a counter between 0-200 - I usually drop it when I load the data since it is the same as the row index. The problem I currently have is in the plot, when I use `imshow()` to plot my figure, it uses the row and column index as the axis ticks. This is fine for my Y axis, since it is the same as my values in column 0; the problem is with the X-axis which has index values between 1-1000, whereas I would like to plot it on axis with actual values of X (i.e. 381.3, 393.3, 200.6 etc). How could I accomplish that?

Currently this is what I get:
[image]

Here is the code I use so far:

```
rawData = pd.read_csv('heme_mpc_drift2.csv', delimiter=',')
rawData_drop=rawData.drop(rawData[[101,102]], axis=1, inplace=False)
xaxis = rawData_drop.ix[0,1:]
yaxis = rawData_drop.ix[1:,0]
plt.figure(figsize=[10,5])
plt.ylim([200,0])
plt.imshow(rawData_drop, cmap=cmaps.plasma, interpolation="none", aspect='auto', vmax=500000)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

I was hoping to use the `xaxis` and `yaxis` in the `imshow()` somewhere, however haven't figured out where. I have tried using `extent` in `imshow()` but it only converts the values from range of 1-100 to whatever new range I give it.

I would appreciate any suggestions.

EDIT 1: 
Added an example of what I am looking for:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with `imshow`, just call `xticks` on your `plt` object

```
plt.xticks(range(len(xaxis)), xaxis, size='small')
```

#### update

In order to make your x-axis also in scale with values while in the same time each observation is just a point I would suggest not to use imshow at all. The plot you are looking for is actually a **scatter** plot, as you have **very little** data points as compared to the whole image. Imshow is generally for **dense plots**.

`plt.scatter` would obviously scale by itself once feeded with your x-values. You can also make it black-background etc. In fact, your included example looks like a scatter plot with pixel-wide markers.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Perhaps I didn't make it clear in the question. I don't just want to have the tick labels on my x-axis but also have the separation between the values w.r.t x-values. Currently the values are plotted next to each other (separation of 1 unit) whereas I would like them to take their actual position (i.e. 381.3, 393.3, 200.6 etc).

Comment: I don't think it can be plotted as a `plt.scatter` because I would have to use values between 1-200 (first column) as my y-axis, and values from 1-1500 (first row) as my x-axis; the plot would then lose all information about the intensity with regards to `x,y` values. I suppose it does not necessarily have to be `imshow` but could also be `hist2d` or `contourf` plot.

Comment: you have x, y and color in scatter, so you have 3 values to work with, exactly in the same way as here.